# Return a Single Map in IBATIS

Tags: sql, orm, ibatis, mybatis

I have a SqlMap query that returns 2 columns, an ID and a string.  I know how to return a list of maps where the ID is the key and the string is the value.  There is one list item for each row returned.

How can I return 1 map with the IDs as keys and strings as values?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use resultType as Map and if query is returning mutilple rows then in DAO you need to handle it using `List<Map<String,Object>>`